# making static objects in box2d

Tags: c++, box2d, openframeworks, triangulation

Dear stackoverflowers,

I am trying to use a static (solid) body in ofxBox2d in openFrameworks. Because it's a concave object I am breaking it up in little triangles with the triangulation function of ofxBox2d. The triangulation is working fine as long as I don't create the body as static (ie density of zero).

So in my code I have:

```
//create shape here//

//triangulate shape here//

// now loop through all the triangles and make a box2d triangle
for (int i=0; i<tris.size(); i++)
{
      ofPtr<ofxBox2dPolygon> triangle = ofPtr<ofxBox2dPolygon>(new ofxBox2dPolygon);
      triangle.get()->addTriangle(tris[i].a, tris[i].b, tris[i].c);
      triangle.get()->setPhysics(1, 0, 0); //density, bounce, friction
      //triangle.get()->body->SetType(b2_staticBody);
      triangle.get()->create(box2d.getWorld());
      polyShapes.push_back(triangle);
    }
```

Please see [this](http://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/making-static-objects-in-ofxbox2d-what-am-i-doing-wrong/15584) link for 2 pictures showing the problem.

In the **top** picture : The object is dynamic (density > 0), it is triangulated properly but it is moved by the forces of the falling balls because it is dynamic. In red: what the original shape looks like.

In the **bottom** picture: If I set the density to 0 (or explicitly set it to static by uncomment the "SetType" line in the code above then my object is not drawn correctly (notice lines in top left corner of image) but behaves just like before (ie. balls pass through it, but they bump into "ghost" triangles); In red: the original (input) shape - or the solid object I expect.

I have written [this](http://forum.openframeworks.cc/uploads/default/3623/61315219c5e09e11.zip) small program the code of which I am attaching (openFrameworks).

I have tried my best to make a simple case to prove the point. Any help much appreciated :).
Thank you.

Comment: Do you get the same problem with a regular shape, eg. a simple circle or square?

Comment: No. I don't. A simple circle or triangle would work. If I enter 4 points trying to imitate a rect and it passes through the triangulation then it does not behave properly. Regarding rectangles , if it is a box2dRect it is fine, but if I enter 4 points into the polyline, attempt to triangulate between them in order to end up with 2 triangles that make a rect, then again things don't behave properly. The shape is not what I expected.

Comment: So it's the triangulation process that screws things up right? Is it generating triangle vertices in counter-clockwise order?

Comment: @iforce2d does the order matter?

Comment: Yes, that's why I mentioned it :) The 'ghost' triangles he mentions are a common symptom of reversed vertex ordering.

Comment: @iforce2d the only difference between "screwed-up" (ghost) triangles and correct ones is whether I make the object static or not. The triangulation works when I setup the triangle as a dynamic object. It's when I make it static (density 0), that it messes things up.
I am baffled. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I made an even simpler example to demonstrate the heart of the problem and posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23386433/box2d-triangulation-of-static-body if anybody would like to take a shot. Thanks :)