# box2d triangulation of static body

Tags: c++, box2d, openframeworks, triangulation

I have posted on this before, but to no avail. Sorry for slightly repeating myself but I have tried to figure this out and I haven't been able to. I am probably not understanding something in box2d. I therefore wrote a **very simplified** example to highlight the issue.

In my code I simply create a rectangle. I triangulate it and then I add it to a box2d world. If I define the object as a dynamic object (density > 0) it is reacting to the walls and objects within the scene [see images here](http://forum.openframeworks.cc/t/ofxbox2d-triangulation-of-a-static-body-simple-example-of-bug/15634/last).

If I declare it as a static (density=0) then the triangulation is messed up, as you can see in the link above.
Basically it's the setPhysics line that makes all the difference between the two scenarios.

```
#include "ofApp.h"

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::setup()
{
    // Box2d
    box2d.init();
    box2d.createGround();
    box2d.setFPS(30.0);
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::update()
{
    shape.clear();

    //A rectangle with a chunk taken out, making a concave shape
    shape.addVertex(ofPoint(mouseX, mouseY));
    shape.addVertex(ofPoint(mouseX+0, mouseY+200));
    shape.addVertex(ofPoint(mouseX+200, mouseY+200));
    shape.addVertex(ofPoint(mouseX+200, mouseY));

    shape.simplify();
    ofPolyline outline = shape;
    ofPolyline resampled = shape.getResampledBySpacing(45);

    vector <TriangleShape> tris;
    tris = triangulatePolygonWithOutline(resampled, outline);

    polyShapes.clear();

    // now loop through all the triangles and make a box2d triangle
    for (int i=0; i<tris.size(); i++)
    {
          ofPtr<ofxBox2dPolygon> triangle = ofPtr<ofxBox2dPolygon>(new ofxBox2dPolygon);
          triangle.get()->addTriangle(tris[i].a, tris[i].b, tris[i].c);
          triangle.get()->setPhysics(1, 0, 0); //density, bounce, friction
          triangle.get()->create(box2d.getWorld());
          //triangle.get()->body->SetType(b2_staticBody);
          polyShapes.push_back(triangle);
    }

    box2d.update();
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------
void ofApp::draw()
{
    ofBackground(125);

    ofSetColor(255);
    ofNoFill();
    for (int i=0; i<polyShapes.size(); i++)
    {
        polyShapes[i].get()->draw();
        ofCircle(polyShapes[i].get()->getPosition(), 3);
    }
}
```

The code for the above program can be downloaded [here](http://forum.openframeworks.cc/uploads/default/3635/2774efdfdf1e59ea.zip) (for openFrameworks). Any help very much appreciated. I have to deliver something to a client and have been hitting my head against the wall with this one.

Comment: For a 'simplified' version, I was not expecting to see the triangulation code in there still - it really confuses the issue. Did you log out the points given to addTriangle to make sure they are in counter-clockwise order? How does one set the position of the body with this API? I wonder if openFrameworks does something silly like assuming all static bodies are located at (0,0) and the body position is taken from the center of mass, since it certainly looks like that in the second screenshot. To be honest I think your best hope is the openFrameworks forum.

Comment: @iforce2d what do you mean by "Did you log out the points given to addTriangle"? you think the `cw` or `ccw` direction of vertex insertion matters? it seems as if there may be some bug here, but can you verify that this is a problem of the OF wrapper and not the box2d itself?

Comment: Logging means to print them out so you can see what actual values are being used there. Better still, take the triangulation code out of this completely, since it's only clouding the issue. As I already said in the other question, the ordering of the vertices most likely does matter which is the reason I bring it up. I can verify that in the original C++ version of Box2D, making a body static instead of dynamic does not cause any of the chaotic results you are seeing. I don't know anything about OF, but generally a port/wrapper is supposed to produce the same results as the original.